# how to use jquery and link_to_function in rails 3.1

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I can't figure out how to use jquery and link_to_function in rails 3.1. i have been working with episode 197 of railscasts but it won't work with 3.1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

firebug is giving me the error

> remove_fields is not defined

here is my code. thanks for all your help.

Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.0.rc4'
```

_form.html.erb

```
<div class="fields">
<p>
    <%= f.label :sample_number %>
    <%= f.text_field :sample_number, :size=> 1  %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>  
    <%= link_to_remove_fields "remove", f %><br>
```

application_helper.rb

```
def link_to_remove_fields(name, f)
    f.hidden_field(:_destroy) + link_to_function(name, "remove_fields(this)")
  end
```

cupping.js.coffee

```
   function remove_fields(link) {
  $(link).prev("input[type=hidden]").val("1");
  $(link).closest(".fields").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

installed and updated gem 'sprockets', '2.0.0.beta.13'
and it works. now the assets load

Answer (score 0):

Is the cupping.js.coffee file correctly loaded (NET tab in FireBug)?

Comment: GET application.js is listed (in red) and //= require_tree . is in the application.js file thank you.

Comment: status on my css and js is 404.